How to auto paginate a large CSV table in LaTeX?
I have the following LaTeX document:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]\centering
    \adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
    \csvreader[
        respect all,
        tabular=|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|,
        table head=\hline ID & Project & Summary & Type & Component(s) & Description & Module & Version \\ \hline\hline,
        late after line=\\\hline
    ]{random_data.csv}{}
    {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii}
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}

The CSV file is a simple 8-column with 400 lines, containing random values, such as:
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
... 400 lines ...

How can I convert this LaTeX document to a PDF where the table is divided across multiple pages, depending on the CSV lines?
I tried using longtable, but run into compiling issues. The latex code like this is perfect I just really need the pagination part.

A table environment does not allow page breaks. Also you should never scale elements which contain text. Choose a suitable font size instead.

... and have a look at https://www.darkhorseanalytics.com/blog/clear-off-the-table

"I tried using longtable, but run into compiling issues." Please share the [mcve] of your code, including any errors you get when trying to compile.


don't use a table environment, it does not permit page breaks
don't scale elements which contain text. Either choose a suitable font size instead or change the table so it fits within the available text width
instead of a normal tabular, use a longtable. This allows page breaks


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{random_data.csv}
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
50,9,81,85,79,96,46,33
3,24,63,91,8,82,95,55
9,72,72,40,76,40,66,12
57,71,67,58,30,83,95,93
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

%\begin{table}[htb]\centering
%    \adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
    \csvreader[
        respect all,
        longtable=|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|,
        table head=\hline ID & Project & Sum. & Type & Comp. & Desc. & Module & Version \\ \hline\hline,
        late after line=\\\hline
    ]{random_data.csv}{}
    {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii}
%    }
%\end{table}

\end{document}


Thank you, your answer helped me with my problem. Just had to fix the width size issue, I used \fontsize{4pt}{6pt}\selectfont before \csvreader to adapt my custom csv to the page.
